# /usr/bin/truncate: Argument list too long

Tags: bash, files, xargs, arguments, truncate

I want to use the `truncate` command to create a huge number of small files for testing. I tried the command with a small number of files (100) and it worked. When I changed the number to 1000000, it reports an error:

```
root:[~/data]# truncate -s 1k {1..100}
root:[~/data]# rm -rf *
root:[~/data]# truncate -s 1k {1..1000000}
-bash: /usr/bin/truncate: Argument list too long
root:[~/data]#
```

How can I solve it? I have a sense that `xargs` could be used, but I can't make it work.

Comment: What design decision led to you needing a million files in the same directory? Ugh!

Comment: I want to benchmark different ways of deleting these files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do

```
echo {1..1000000} | xargs truncate -s 1k
```

<sub>(That should work with a shell with a builtin echo that isn't subject to command line length limits. Also `xargs` splits the input on any whitespace by default, but that doesn't matter here.)</sub>

The above might use awful amounts of memory, so using `seq` like in mosvy's comment might be better:

```
seq 1 1000000 | xargs truncate -s 1k
```

I usually use a loop though (this starts from `000000`, not `1`, and has leading zeroes in all names):

```
for i in {000..999}; do
    touch "$i"{000..999}
done
```

Having a million files in a single directory is probably going to be slow, so unless you're testing just that, it might be a good idea to spread them into subdirectories instead, say:

```
for i in {000..999}; do
    mkdir "$i"
    touch "$i"/{000..999}
done
```

Note that if you can't create the files because they don't fit on one command line and work around that somehow, you probably won't be able to remove them with `rm -f *` either. You'd need to remove the whole tree recursively, or do something like `find -maxdepth 1 -type f -delete`.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding a note to @ilkkachu's excellent answer to explain the logic. The command

```
truncate -s 1k {1..1000000}
```

calls `truncate` with *one million* arguments plus three (`truncate` (`argv[0]`), `-s` and `1k`) which is well over the default limit of the cumulative number and size of arguments and environment variables for the `execve()` system call on most systems. Hence the *"Argument list too long"* error.

Instead, the proposed solution

```
seq 1 1000000 | xargs truncate -s 1k
```

just runs `truncate` (via `xargs`) as many times as needed with as many arguments (beside `truncate`, `-s` and `1k` which are repeated in each invocation) as possible so as to avoid that limitation of the `execve()` system call.